# Secrets.yml is not loading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some data in my local `secrets.yml`. Now I have added 2 more secrets, 
but in rails console these secrets are not coming.
Even I edit old keys in the secrets.yml and then open console again but still not able to view the updated data.
It means that secrets.yml is not loading properly.

I tried to execute `bin/spring stop` but no luck.

Is it because, secrets.yml is in gitignore?

I also try to remove secrets.yml from the application. Then open rails console again.
I can still see the old secrets.
I changed the secrets.yml manually in the **netbeans** editor.

I have executed `Rails.application.secrets.api_key`
I can see it. Then using netbeans, I added 1 more key i.e. `secret_key` but I am unable to access it in rails console using `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key`

I reopened the terminal several times but no luck.

My Rails version is 5.1.4

Comment: Which editor are you using? And how do you edit your secrets.yml? Can you provide more detail to the question like adding commands you execute at your terminal?

Comment: Did you edit the secrets.yml manually? The proper way would be to run this in the terminal: `rails credentials:edit` and change it there. If you still don't see it in your rails console, try a new terminal window and re-run `rails c`. Need more detail in general - as Semih pointed out above.

Comment: @MikeK: Rails credentials is not a part of Rails 5.1 it comes in rails 6

Comment: @SemihArslanoğlu Updated the question with the details

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your secrets.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just restarted my computer , open terminal again and it works.
Strange, I dont understand the issue but it works

Answer (score 1):

After Rails 5.1 you can't update your secrets.yml by manually. You need to first decrypt it, edit it and then encrypt again. Safest way to do so is following these commands in console.

First you need to run this command in your console. I'm not sure if it can be used by netbeans so i will write manual for vim editor, which every console can handle.

```
EDITOR="vim" bin/rails secrets:edit
```

In here you need to very careful because most of the developers having hard time using vim editor.

1. Press i button
2. Make your changes
3. Press escape button
4. Then press ':' button and type wq (it should look like this :wq) and press enter
5. You will see a message like this `File encrypted and saved.` in your console.
6. You can check your secrets.yml by again typing `EDITOR="vim" bin/rails secrets:edit` to make sure everything is updated correctly

[Changing secrets.yml in rails 5.1+](https://rubyinrails.com/2018/02/24/rails-5-1-encrypted-secrets-management-feature/)

Comment: I was able to edit the secrets file earlier, so no need for above